# How to apply css to all the divs in hierarchy in HTML?

Tags: css, html

How to apply class abc to all the divs?
Will you please explain?

```
<div class='abc'>
</div>
```

Comment: Add `class="abc"` to all the DIVs that you need to be styled with that class.

Comment: Same as you've applied in first div!

Comment: do you want to add abc class to all the divs or do you want the 'abc' class properties rendered on the divs inside?

Comment: I want that class abc to all divs

Comment: this wont possible without javaScript

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To apply the same style, use:

```
.abc, .abc div { /* your style */ }
```

Explanation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Getting_started

Answer (score 0):

Using Jquery you could do

```
$('.abc').find('div').addClass('abc');
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/XD2fu/1/)

Comment: Do you mean .addClass?

Comment: thank you, yes corrected the same also added a jsfiddle for the same

Answer (score -1):

yup obviously .abc,.abc div{ styling} will do your task.
if u apply formating like .abc{ stylng }
this will become the formatting of your div having class abc
and if you apply .abc div{ styling } this will become the formatting of your div inside the class .abc but not on the div of class abc
and to apply formatting on all the div including the div of class abc
you must use 
.abc,.abc div{ styling... }....